# Solving a big z3 query within a python program involving arrays

Tags: python, z3

I have a formula stating a desired property about a three dimensional array of size 480x200x3. This property must be checked over successive instances of such an array.

My approach was to create the following string spec:

```
[ declaration* (declare-const {varname} (Array Int (Array Int (Array Int Int)))) ]
[ ...
    (assert (and
        (= (select (select (select {varname} 0) 0) 0) varvalue[0][0][0])
        (= (select (select (select {varname} 0) 0) 1) varvalue[0][0][1])
        (= (select (select (select {varname} 0) 0) 2) varvalue[0][0][2])
        ...
        (= (select (select (select {varname} 0) 199) 0) varvalue[0][199][0])
        (= (select (select (select {varname} 0) 199) 1) varvalue[0][199][1])
        (= (select (select (select {varname} 0) 199) 2) varvalue[0][199][2])
        ...
        (= (select (select (select {varname} 479) 0) 0) varvalue[0][0][0])
        (= (select (select (select {varname} 479) 0) 1) varvalue[0][0][1])
        (= (select (select (select {varname} 479) 0) 2) varvalue[0][0][2])
        ...
        (= (select (select (select {varname} 479) 199) 0) varvalue[479][199][0])
        (= (select (select (select {varname} 479) 199) 1) varvalue[479][199][1])
        (= (select (select (select {varname} 479) 199) 2) varvalue[479][199][2])
    ))
    [formula]
]
```

and then, executing the following code:

```
temp_solver = z3.Solver()
temp_solver.from_string(spec)
negation_is_sat = (z3.sat == temp_solver.check())
```

but it takes a ridiculous amount of time to be solved. Of course; it involves an and clause with 288000 equalities in it, all very simple but still

What would be a more efficient (in the context of Z3) way of doing this?

Comment: Is `varvalue` only consisting of constants? If so, then don't create the array, directly use it as is. If it has symbolic values in it, then it all depends on what kind of other constraints you have on the system; you need to provide more details. In general, avoid using strings and parsing from them; simply use z3py features to assert them.

Comment: The main problem with using z3 programmatically is that, while varname is present in every instance, the set variables involved in the problem to solve vary dynamically so I need to build the specification in run-time... maybe resorting to a hybrid approach were the dynamic part of the problem is built by parsing a string while the fixed one involving varname is added programmatically works better. Thank you very much for the insight.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you can construct the string, you can surely use the API to make the corresponding calls? I'm not sure why it has to involve strings at all. (Constructing/deconstructing the string will be costly, regardless how you do it.) If you can post small instance of your problem as executable code, we can see how to use the z3 API directly, instead of going through strings. (There might be legitimate reasons to go through strings, like trying to use different SMT solvers with the same output; but that doesn't sound like a concern in this case.)

Comment: Most of the cost came from the use of an existential quantified subformula that I was capable to factored out as a separate formula. Now, analyzing them separately made the cost additive instead of multiplicative so the time spent is a lot less. I will explore further optimizations later. Thanks a lot.